# Python ISO datetime contains 'T' character

Tags: python, json, datetime

How can I make this lambda get a timestamp that doesn't include the `T` in the timestamp?

```
@app.route("/bookings", methods=['GET'])
def bookings():
    bookings = Booking.query.all()
    dictList = []
    for b in bookings:
        dictList.append(b.as_dict())
    dthandler = lambda obj: (
                    obj.isoformat()
                    if isinstance(obj, datetime.datetime)
                    or isinstance(obj, datetime.date)
                    else None)
    return json.dumps(dictList, default=dthandler)
```

eg timestamp:

```
2015-04-11T01:30:00
```

Comment: Tip: `isinstance()` can take a tuple of types for the second argument, so `if isinstance(obj, (datetime.date, datetime.datetime))` would be enough.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm trying to have the 'T' excluded from the resulting timestamp

Comment: But that has nothing to do with UTC timezones. Just use `obj.isoformat(' ')` then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`datetime.isoformat()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat) takes an argument: the separator to use. It defaults to `'T'` if omitted; if you want something else, then pass in that instead:

```
obj.isoformat(' ')
```

Quoting the documentation:

> The optional argument *sep* (default `'T'`) is a one-character separator, placed between the date and time portions of the result.

You can also convert the object to a string here; [`datetime.__str__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.__str__) is basically the same thing as `datetime.isoformat(' ')`.

Demo:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> obj = datetime(2015, 4, 21, 20, 0, 0)
>>> obj.isoformat()
'2015-04-21T20:00:00'
>>> obj.isoformat(' ')
'2015-04-21 20:00:00'
```

Only the `datetime.isoformat()` method takes that argument; `date.isoformat()` does not; you'll have to adjust your `default` handler to differentiate between `date` and `datetime` objects for this to work, or just use `str()` on either:

```
dthandler = lambda obj: (
                obj.isoformat(' ') if isinstance(obj, datetime.datetime)
                else obj.isoformat() if isinstance(obj, datetime.date)
                else None)
```

or

```
dthandler = lambda obj: (
                str(obj) if isinstance(obj, (datetime.datetime, datetime.date))
                else None)
```

Comment: for a datetime object, you could call `str(obj)` instead of `obj.isoformat(' ')`.